# Somebody knows how to solve 401 Unauthorized error with Clockify API using axios and node js

Tags: node.js, axios, clockify

Does someone know why I'm getting a 401 Unauthorized error when I try to post a request to add a time entry even though I have added my API key?

I'm using Axios and node js, and this is the information and how I am making the request. However, I am able to get a list of users using the axios.get() method with the same API key, so I'm not sure why the post request says I'm not Unauthorized.

```js
const insertOwnTimeEntryUrl = `${url}/workspaces/${workspaceId}/time-entries`;

let payload = {
  start: "2022-05-05T17:10:00.000Z",
  billable: "true",
  description: "Test insert 1",
  projectId: projectIdToInsert,
  taskId: taskIdToInsert,
  end: "",
  tagIds: [tagIdToInsert],
};
let headers = {
  "X-Api-Key": key,
};

let clockifyData = {
  headers,
  payload,
};

async function addNewEntry(clockifyData, insertOwnTimeEntryUrl, key) {
  return (response = await axios
    .post(`${insertOwnTimeEntryUrl}`, {
      data: clockifyData.payload,
      headers: {
        "X-Api-Key": key,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error.response.data.message);
      return;
    }));
}
addNewEntry(clockifyData, insertOwnTimeEntryUrl, key);
```

Comment: The only applicable answer is that your `key` is incorrect. Also, `\`${insertOwnTimeEntryUrl}\`` is a totally redundant template literal. Your variable is already a string so just use `axios.post(insertOwnTimeEntryUrl, ...`

Comment: However, I am able to get a list of users with the axios.get() method with the same API key.

Comment: Are you sure it's the same key? Have you compared them while debugging? Make sure there's no extra whitespace or other unwanted characters